# Is Spring/Spring-Security affected by CVE-2022-21449?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

is there any scenario where CVE-2022-21449 could lead to an hack/abuse ?

I showed at the github repo of spring security and java.security is widely used, but i do not know how the usage in the library could lead to a security flaw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a vulnerability in Spring / Spring Security *per se*.  The vulnerability is in the JVM itself.  Specifically, it is in signature checking for ECDSA (Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm) signatures.

In order for this to be a problem in a Spring based application, the application needs to rely on ECDSA verification for some aspect of its security.  A common use of signature verification is when your application fetches code from an untrusted 3rd party, and runs it in a security sandbox.  An attacker could inject a JAR with a faked signature.

Another possibility is if either your application or Spring itself is using ECDSA signatures itself for some purpose.

---

But you could say that this is moot.  If you just upgrade the Java installation that your Spring applications are using, you don't need to dig more deeply to see if they were (indirectly) vulnerable.